# How to call PACK in JavaScript

Tags: michelson, javascript, pack, bytes, serialization

In my smart contract in LIGO I serialize some data using `Bytes.pack` which calls the underlying `PACK` Michelson instruction. In my case, the function signature is `(nat, address, nat) -> bytes`. Does any JavaScript/TypeScript library like Taquito have a functionality to emulate this LIGO instruction or do I have to implement that myself?

Comment: I am fine by implementing this self as a unit8 array or a hex string in JavaScript. If that is necessary, I would like a link to how `PACK`'s serialization is implemented, though.

Answer (score 2):

Taquito has this functionality: the [packData method in the RPC client package](https://tezostaquito.io/typedoc/classes/_taquito_rpc.rpcclient.html#packdata).

Comment: Very nice. But is there a reason the calculation has to go through a node?

Comment: @ThorkilVærge there are no obligations. It’s simply easier to implement it like that. ConseilJS has this functionality and I’m surprised Taquito doesn’t (maybe it does elsewhere?). There are other implementations that I know of (pytezos, SmartPy) that don’t fully answer your question (easily callable from JavaScript) but prove that it’s quite possible.

Comment: The other thing with the SmartPy and ConseilJS implementation is that we don't know yet for sure if they are 100% identical to the protocol's implementation. Extracting it as a library would be safest.

Comment: @ArthurB I’m more than looking forward to it.